# How to get two different search forms in Magento one fulltext and one title search?

Tags: php, magento, templates, search, block

I want to do two different search types in two different search forms.

I got the head search in fulltext and i created a quicksearch.phtml to edit this as a title only search.

Is there a way to set the "title only search" settings in my quicksearch.phtml or the form.mini.phtml?

Code of quicksearch.phtml:

```
<?php
/* @var $this Mage_Core_Block_Template */
/* @var $catalogSearchHelper Mage_Catalogsearch_Helper_Data */
$catalogSearchHelper =  $this->helper('catalogsearch');
?>
<form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">
    <div class="form-search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="search" type="text" name="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getQueryParamName() ?>" value="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getEscapedQueryText() ?>" class="input-text form-control" maxlength="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getMaxQueryLength();?>">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Search')) ?>" class="btn btn-default"></button>
            </span>
        </div>

        <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
            var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->jsQuoteEscape($this->__('Suchbegriff eingeben...')) ?>');
            searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
        //]]>
        </script>
    </div>
</form>
```

by the way i got Magento 1.9.2.4

Here is the Helper code of it. Perhaps i could create a new copy of it and edit this one?

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_CatalogSearch
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2016 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Catalog search helper
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_CatalogSearch_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Query variable name
     */
    const QUERY_VAR_NAME = 'q';

    /*
     * Maximum query length
     */
    const MAX_QUERY_LEN  = 200;

    /**
     * Query object
     *
     * @var Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query
     */
    protected $_query;

    /**
     * Query string
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_queryText;

    /**
     * Note messages
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_messages = array();

    /**
     * Is a maximum length cut
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isMaxLength = false;

    /**
     * Search engine model
     *
     * @var Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext_Engine
     */
    protected $_engine;

    /**
     * Retrieve search query parameter name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getQueryParamName()
    {
        return self::QUERY_VAR_NAME;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve query model object
     *
     * @return Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query
     */
    public function getQuery()
    {
        if (!$this->_query) {
            $this->_query = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')
                ->loadByQuery($this->getQueryText());
            if (!$this->_query->getId()) {
                $this->_query->setQueryText($this->getQueryText());
            }
        }
        return $this->_query;
    }

    /**
     * Is a minimum query length
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isMinQueryLength()
    {
        $minQueryLength = $this->getMinQueryLength();
        $thisQueryLength = Mage::helper('core/string')->strlen($this->getQueryText());
        return !$thisQueryLength || $minQueryLength !== '' && $thisQueryLength < $minQueryLength;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve search query text
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getQueryText()
    {
        if (!isset($this->_queryText)) {
            $this->_queryText = $this->_getRequest()->getParam($this->getQueryParamName());
            if ($this->_queryText === null) {
                $this->_queryText = '';
            } else {
                /* @var $stringHelper Mage_Core_Helper_String */
                $stringHelper = Mage::helper('core/string');
                $this->_queryText = is_array($this->_queryText) ? ''
                    : $stringHelper->cleanString(trim($this->_queryText));

                $maxQueryLength = $this->getMaxQueryLength();
                if ($maxQueryLength !== '' && $stringHelper->strlen($this->_queryText) > $maxQueryLength) {
                    $this->_queryText = $stringHelper->substr($this->_queryText, 0, $maxQueryLength);
                    $this->_isMaxLength = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->_queryText;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve HTML escaped search query
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEscapedQueryText()
    {
        return $this->escapeHtml($this->getQueryText());
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve suggest collection for query
     *
     * @return Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Query_Collection
     */
    public function getSuggestCollection()
    {
        return $this->getQuery()->getSuggestCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve result page url and set "secure" param to avoid confirm
     * message when we submit form from secure page to unsecure
     *
     * @param   string $query
     * @return  string
     */
    public function getResultUrl($query = null)
    {
        return $this->_getUrl('catalogsearch/result', array(
            '_query' => array(self::QUERY_VAR_NAME => $query),
            '_secure' => $this->_getApp()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->isSecure()
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve suggest url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSuggestUrl()
    {
        return $this->_getUrl('catalogsearch/ajax/suggest', array(
            '_secure' => $this->_getApp()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Get App
     *
     * @return Mage_Core_Model_App
     */
    protected function _getApp()
    {
        return Mage::app();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve search term url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSearchTermUrl()
    {
        return $this->_getUrl('catalogsearch/term/popular');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve advanced search URL
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAdvancedSearchUrl()
    {
        return $this->_getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve minimum query length
     *
     * @param mixed $store
     * @return int|string
     */
    public function getMinQueryLength($store = null)
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query::XML_PATH_MIN_QUERY_LENGTH, $store);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve maximum query length
     *
     * @param mixed $store
     * @return int|string
     */
    public function getMaxQueryLength($store = null)
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query::XML_PATH_MAX_QUERY_LENGTH, $store);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve maximum query words count for like search
     *
     * @param mixed $store
     * @return int
     */
    public function getMaxQueryWords($store = null)
    {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query::XML_PATH_MAX_QUERY_WORDS, $store);
    }

    /**
     * Add Note message
     *
     * @param string $message
     * @return Mage_CatalogSearch_Helper_Data
     */
    public function addNoteMessage($message)
    {
        $this->_messages[] = $message;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set Note messages
     *
     * @param array $messages
     * @return Mage_CatalogSearch_Helper_Data
     */
    public function setNoteMessages(array $messages)
    {
        $this->_messages = $messages;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Current Note messages
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getNoteMessages()
    {
        return $this->_messages;
    }

    /**
     * Check query of a warnings
     *
     * @param mixed $store
     * @return Mage_CatalogSearch_Helper_Data
     */
    public function checkNotes($store = null)
    {
        if ($this->_isMaxLength) {
            $this->addNoteMessage($this->__('Maximum Search query length is %s. Your query was cut.', $this->getMaxQueryLength()));
        }

        /* @var $stringHelper Mage_Core_Helper_String */
        $stringHelper = Mage::helper('core/string');

        $searchType = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::XML_PATH_CATALOG_SEARCH_TYPE);
        if ($searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_COMBINE
            || $searchType == Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext::SEARCH_TYPE_LIKE
        ) {
            $wordsFull = $stringHelper->splitWords($this->getQueryText(), true);
            $wordsLike = $stringHelper->splitWords($this->getQueryText(), true, $this->getMaxQueryWords());
            if (count($wordsFull) > count($wordsLike)) {
                $wordsCut = array_map(array($this, 'escapeHtml'), array_diff($wordsFull, $wordsLike));
                $this->addNoteMessage(
                    $this->__('Maximum words count is %1$s. In your search query was cut next part: %2$s.', $this->getMaxQueryWords(), join(' ', $wordsCut))
                );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Join index array to string by separator
     * Support 2 level array gluing
     *
     * @param array $index
     * @param string $separator
     * @return string
     */
    public function prepareIndexdata($index, $separator = ' ')
    {
        $_index = array();
        foreach ($index as $value) {
            if (!is_array($value)) {
                $_index[] = $value;
            }
            else {
                $_index = array_merge($_index, $value);
            }
        }
        return join($separator, $_index);
    }

    /**
     * Get current search engine resource model
     *
     * @return object
     */
    public function getEngine()
    {
        if (!$this->_engine) {
            $engine = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/search/engine');

            /**
             * This needed if there already was saved in configuration some none-default engine
             * and module of that engine was disabled after that.
             * Problem is in this engine in database configuration still set.
             */
            if ($engine && Mage::getConfig()->getResourceModelClassName($engine)) {
                $model = Mage::getResourceSingleton($engine);
                if ($model && $model->test()) {
                    $this->_engine = $model;
                }
            }
            if (!$this->_engine) {
                $this->_engine = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalogsearch/fulltext_engine');
            }
        }

        return $this->_engine;
    }
}
```

Comment: i know, that the settings are normaly made in the backend/admin panel but this have to be a different search on the same site.

Answer (score 1):

Since the basic search in Magento is based on a fulltext index, which is created from all the attributes with the setting "use in quicksearch/advanced search", I guess it will not be that easy.

You could build a small extension with a controller that only delivers results for your title attribute.

Cheers.

Comment: isnt there any options which are set in the admin panel for this? I mean couldnt i just hardcode this option in my function in this template?

Comment: or better how could i edit the Controller hardcoded to get the title search?

Comment: Maybe you can try to use the advanced search and modify it for your needs. There you can search for special attributes.
You can try to submit only the title. Basically your call should look like this then:
http://youstoredomain.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?title=querytext

Comment: Note: You have to set your title to be searchable in advanced search of course. 

Besides this, you just create an extension, add a controller which you call with your ajax query, submit your querytext for the title search to the controller and return results either directly querying the database or filtering a product collection - depends on how many products you will search etc...